# Why is there an endless loop in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to make a one-way list, but I can't find out why an endless loop appears here. The problem is in clearList() method

```
class List
{
private:
  Document document;
  List* nextPtr;
public:
  List()
    :document(), nextPtr(NULL)
  {
    cout << "class List: CONSTRUCTOR (default)\n";
  }

  List(const Document& d)
    :nextPtr(NULL)
  {
    cout << "class List: CONSTRUCTOR (init)\n";
    document = d;
  }

  ~List()
  {
    cout << "class List: DESTRUCTOR\n";
    freeList(this);
  }

  void freeList(List* top)
  {
    if(top != NULL)
      freeList(top->nextPtr);
    delete top;
  }
};
```

Here is the main program:

```
int main()
{
  List list1;

  return 0;
}
```

And here's what I've got

[image]

Comment: `delete top;` is calling the destructor of your object, as `top` is `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your `List` object is destroyed, the destructor will call `freeList` which will do `delete top` where `top` is `this`, causing itself to be destroyed again. The destructor will then call `freeList` again, and so on and so forth.

Seems like really you just want a destructor that does this:

```
~List()
{
  cout << "class List: DESTRUCTOR\n";
  delete nextPtr;
}
```

The `delete` of `nextPtr` will call the next `List`'s destructor, and that will `delete` its next `List`'s pointer and so on. This will stop when `nextPtr` is `NULL` because `delete NULL;` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your `destructor` calls `freeList`, which then calls `delete`, which is going to call your `destructor`. This is going to end badly!

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting an object that is already going out of scope.

That is, `~List()` calls `freeList` with `this`, which `delete` causes `~List()` to be invoked again.

You should not be deleting stack allocated objects.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the underlying problem of manual memory management.